# Derivative of ln of infinite product.

Tags: derivatives, infinite-product

I am slightly confused by a problem I have been given, namely:

$$-\frac{d}{dx}\ln(Y(x))$$ with $$Y(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}(1+e^{-xa_i})$$.

Now I have alredy looked at what the infinite product will turn into, which I think will be $1$ plus a sum of all possible subsets of and including $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}e^{-xa_i}$, but I am not sure how I should derive this inner part. Is my approach too complicated?

Comment: Have you tried expressing $\ln(Y(x))$ as $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\ln(1+e^{-xa_i})$, and differentiating term by term?

Comment: Thanks, didn't see it.